# How to extract MP3 from a PDF file?

Tags: windows-8.1, pdf, mp3, extract, attachments

I Have a PDF file that has a lot of MP3 attached to it.

How should I extract them?

Comment: What tools do you have?  This cannot be done with any PDF [Adobe](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1078026) tools at this time.

Comment: You could try using [File Juicer](http://echoone.com/filejuicer/).

Comment: It's pointless suggesting options for you like @NReilingh has so kindly done until you mention your OS.

Comment: @Karan I use windows 8.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) for this as follows:

```
pdftk <PDF file> unpack_files output <output dir>
```

or

```
pdftk <PDF file> unpack_files output PROMPT
```

Answer (score 1):

That isn't a supported feature if you using in Acrobat which can't help you. If the PDF is unsecured and you have the legal rights to extract the audio, it would be possible to locate and decompress the raw file data from the PDF file using third-party tools to read the low-level file structure (a hex editor or Cos editor)